# Get number of customers having 1,2 and more than 3 products

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

Trying to figure out a query which shows the number of customer having 1,2 and more than 3 products. Here are the table name and fields:

- Product(prod_no, prod_cust_id)
- Customer(cust_id)

**Product**

| prod_no | prod_cust_id |
| --- | --- |
| Cheetos1 | WR123 |
| Cheetos2 | WR123 |
| Lay1 | WP232 |
| Prings | WP678 |

**Customer**

| cust_id |
| --- |
| WN999 |
| WR123 |
| WP232 |
| WP678 |

Example of correct query I want to get is:

- 1 Product - 100 customer
- 2 Product - 52 customer
- 3 Products and above - 10 customer

| Product | Customers |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 52 |
| >=3 | 10 |

I tried with the following query

```sql
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT PROD_NO)"Product", CUST_ID"Customers"
  FROM PRODUCT, CUSTOMER
 WHERE PROD_CUST_ID = CUST_ID
HAVING COUNT(PROD_NO) >= 3 --for 3 products and above
GROUP BY CUST_ID
```

But the result is not what I wanted, so close yet so far. I tried only for 3 products and above, but how to add together with 1 product and 2 products.

Please help me out thanks

Comment: indeed `Customer` table is not needed to be presented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be starting with distinctly counting by each column ( `prod_no`,`prod_cust_id` ), and evaluating the three or more products as an individual case within the conditional such as

```sql
WITH prod_cust AS
(
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT prod_no) AS prod_no, 
        DECODE( SIGN(COUNT(DISTINCT prod_cust_id)-2),1,'>=3',
                     COUNT(DISTINCT prod_cust_id) ) AS prod_cust_id
   FROM product
  GROUP BY prod_no 
)
SELECT prod_cust_id AS "Product", SUM(prod_no) AS "Customers"
  FROM prod_cust   
 GROUP BY prod_cust_id 
 ORDER BY 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b6e17c31ef8941893017f4f9b2cecd00)</kbd>

Comment: Awesome solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can first count the no of customers in the product table and then can count them separately. You can try the below query -

```
WITH DATA AS (SELECT P.*, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY prod_cust_id) CNT
                FROM Product P)
SELECT '1' Product, COUNT(CASE WHEN CNT = 1 THEN CNT ELSE NULL END) Customers
  FROM DATA
 UNION ALL
SELECT '2', COUNT(CASE WHEN CNT = 2 THEN CNT ELSE NULL END) 
  FROM DATA
 UNION ALL
SELECT '>=3', COUNT(CASE WHEN CNT >= 3 THEN CNT ELSE NULL END) 
  FROM DATA;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=62768ac889f8292ade0b96012ad3a43f)